# Cannot access external storage - folder missing on emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I cannot access the external storage directory on my emulator. My app has read/write external storage permissions (emulator on Marshmallow), but making a directory fails. I looked at Device Monitor and found that the `sdcard` folder does not exist where I expect it to. Am I missing something or is my emulator corrupt?

[image]

Code I'm using to create the directory. `madeDir` always shows false (and the `mkdirs()` line is always run).

```
//Create directory if it doesn't exist
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "MyApp/";
        // Create the parent path
        File dir = new File(path);
        boolean madeDir = false;
        if (!dir.isDirectory()) {
            madeDir = dir.mkdirs();
        }
```

Yes, I do have external storage permissions, compatible with Marshmallow. The settings on my emulator confirm that they are there. I make the following call and handle the result.

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, requestCode);
```

**Update:** I'm getting this error **after** I have received permissions. I can try over and over and get the same error. If I restart my app, everything works fine. I am confused.

[image]

Comment: We cannot help you with Java code unless you provide the Java code. With regards to `/sdcard`, that hasn't been an actual directory in years. At best, it's a symlink or hardlink or something. If your Nexus 5 is running Android 6.0, DDMS should show the default user's external storage in `/storage/emulated/0`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, thank you for replying. I tried looking the directory you suggested, but it does not exist. I will update my answer with a screenshot. I've also updated it with my java code. (screenshot coming, browser keeps crashing...)

Comment: "My app has read/write external storage permissions (emulator on Marshmallow)" -- where is your code for asking the user for the permission? Note that on Android 6.0+, `<uses-permission>` is insufficient for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. "I tried looking the directory you suggested, but it does not exist" -- then perhaps you did not set up external storage ("SD card") in the AVD.

Comment: Hmm. I made a new VM and the external storage is at `/storage/0Af1-300B`. Anyway, I've determined that creating the directory works *only if I have terminated and restarted my app after being granted permission*. Until I restart the app, the `mkdirs` call gets a Permission Denied error (see updated answer). I understand why I would not have permission after having been granted permission or why restarting my app matters.